# how to operate On List of IIS Application Pools On Remote Server Using Powershell?

Tags: iis, powershell, pool

I am trying to build powershell program which would:

1. connect to the remote server
2. Show number of active IIS app pools on the active server
3. based on the selection (1,2,3,4,....n etc) it would reset app pool

Can you please give me some tips?

Answer (score 4):

Give this a try:

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.Web.Administration')
$sm = [Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager]::OpenRemote('server1')
$sm.ApplicationPools['AppPoolName'].Recycle()
```

Answer (score 3):

Building upon the answers already given, try the following.  It uses powershell remoting, specifically [Invoke-Command](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849719.aspx) so you need to familiarise yourself with that.

```
[cmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$true,ConfirmImpact="High")] 
param
(
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true)] 
    [string]$ComputerName,

    [parameter(Mandatory=$false)] 
    [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]$Credential
)
begin
{
    if (!($Credential))
    {
        # Prompt for credentials if not passed in
        $Credential = get-credential
    }

    $scriptBlock = {

        Import-Module WebAdministration

        # Get all running app pools
        $applicationPools = Get-ChildItem IIS:\AppPools | ? {$_.state -eq "Started"}
        $i = 0

        # Display a basic menu
        Write-Host "`nApplication Pools`n"
        $applicationPools | % {
            "[{0}]`t{1}" -f $i, $($applicationPools[$i].Name)
            $i++
        }

        # Get their choice
        $response = Read-Host -Prompt "`nSelect Application Pool to recycle"

        # Grab the associated object, which will be null 
        # if an out of range choice was entered
        $appPool = $applicationPools[$response]

        if ($appPool)
        {
            "Recycling '{0}'" -f $appPool.name
            $appPool.recycle()
        }
    }
}
process
{
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computerName -Credential $credential -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot help with existing code, but which some links

1. Check out remote powershell sessions [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd819505.aspx)
2. Check out the Web [Server (IIS) Administration Cmdlets in Windows PowerShell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790599.aspx), specialy the [Get-WebApplication](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790554.aspx) and [Get-WebAppPoolState](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790588.aspx)
3. If reset means stop, then you could take a look on [Stop-WebAppPool](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790553.aspx)